# Highcharts.js/Highstock - Time values between date values in x-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If i select a period in my Highstock-chart (Highchart.js) which is less than 6 days (i entered the input via the from and to fields) the x-Axis contains values like this:

```
12:00  20. Jul   12:00  21. Jul  12:00  22. Jul
```

Is there a possibility to remove this time values from the x-Axis (12:00) ?

Or another fix would be to not allow a period selection less than one week...

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: you can use minRange to avoid having smaller period selection than one week: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange Another solution is to use tickPositioner and remove all ticks that don't meet your requirements: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Perfect. Will give it a try right away. Thanks